# ERROR running force:auth:web:login: spawn UNKNOWN

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, vs-code, node.js, node-salesforce

I am getting "ERROR running force:auth:web:login:  spawn UNKNOWN" on Windows 10 when trying to authorize sandbox org from VS Code. I have already tried changing default browsers and have also added "c:\Windows\System32" to the "Path" Environment variable (for both user and system variables). When I try to authorize sandbox org, also when the command is executed browser doesn't open up at all.

Comment: Can you reinstall your sfdx and check? This seems to be an issue from node js side.

Comment: I have tried re-installing all 3 components Node Js, Salesforce CLI as well as VS Code, without any luck. Is there any settings for Node JS that I can set manually?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem as you did, turned out I had powershell disabled via security policy and group policy. I turned it on and it worked for me. Basicly i did the opposite of what is written here:

https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-disable-powershell-windows-10

Make sure your powershell is accessible.

Comment: Is there any other workaround? In my case, powershell is not allowed